# React Native Renaimated 2 failed and ERROR Invariant Violation in while using Drawer Navigation

Tags: react-native, error-handling, navigation-drawer

Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native. ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly for,
Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin? error

Go to project's root directory
Update the *babel.config.js* in following way

```
module.exports = {
      presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
      plugins: [
        "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
      ],
    };
```

Regarding second error, when we used to put code from react native guide directly then we have to change the way react is imported,
Change this
**import * as React from 'react';**
to
**import React from 'react';**
*This will remove ERROR Invariant Violation error.*

Answer (score 0):

That was worked for me finally. Add a few lines in MainApplication.java from this file
https://github.com/software-mansion-labs/reanimated-2-playground/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/reanimated2playground/MainApplication.java

Any cache cleaning, reanimated babel plugin setup advices did not help.

Add this imports.

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage;
```

Also add this method in ReactNativeHostWrapper

```
   protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
          return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage();
        }
```

And finally delete package-lock.json, reinstall node_modules, clean npm/yarn cache.